# omitting columns in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

my dataframes looks somewhat like

```
df1:
|2022|2021|2020|2019|2018|
|----|----|----|----|----|
|33  |    |20  |67  |23  |

df2:
|2022|2021|2020|2019|2018|
|----|----|----|----|----|
|33  | 89 |    |20  |95  |
```

as there are multiple data frames containing different values in different years so i cant do the column selection manually. is there anyway I can filter out columns that contains values for the latest 3 years so that the output would be

```
for df1 :
|2022|2020|2019|
|----|----|----|
|33  |20  |67  |

For df2:
|2022|2021|2019|
|----|----|----|
|33  | 89 |20  |
```

Answer (score 3):

Assuming the columns are sorted by ascending year (if not add a `.sort_index(axis=1, ascending=False)` step initially):

```
out = df.dropna(axis=1).iloc[:, :3]
```

output for `df1`:

```
   2022  2020  2019
0    33    20    67
```

output for `df2`:

```
   2022  2021  2019
0    33    89    20
```

###### alternative:

Using [`nlargest`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.nlargest.html) which might be more efficient on very large dataframes if the columns are not sorted.

```
out = df[df.dropna(axis=1).columns.to_series().nlargest(3)]
```

Comment: I got the same solution, but later, @mozway! ;-) +1